# Angular Dart material-radio not showing up

Tags: angular-dart

in dart file I have

```
    directives: [coreDirectives, formDirectives, MaterialIconComponent, MaterialRadioComponent, MaterialRadioGroupComponent,  ],
  providers: [materialProviders,],
```

html has

```
 <material-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected">
                    <material-radio
                            [disabled]="false"
                            [value]="'f1'"> First
                    </material-radio>
                    <material-radio
                            [disabled]="false"
                            [value]="'f2'"> Second
                    </material-radio>
                </material-radio-group>
```

When I run it I see:

radio_button_unchecked  First
radio_button_unchecked Second

What css am I missing ?

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot of the UI?

Comment: Did you import material icons in your index.html ? documentation here https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_icon.